# Retrieve Accept-Language browser settings in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Every call to the server gets the Accept-Language value, but can I get that information within the Silverlight client?

I found `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.BrowserInformation` but it doesn't contain the user language preferences.

Comment: It would help if we knew why you want it?  For example it maybe that `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` or `CurrentUICulture` is what you are looking for.

Comment: That is part of the information. Accept-Language contains a list of languages the user understands, in decreasing order of preference. If the resources are not available in the user's preferred language, I would try to match an alternate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the value that you would get via "Request.Headers["Accept-Language"]" in .net? I would just add a method to the web service that provides data to your silverlight to return it, then request it from Silverlight when the app starts up.

I usually back my Silverlight application with a server-side .net WCF service, so I would just add a method for this kind of information.

If you don't want a webservice method, you can also pass it to your Silverlight application at startup using initParms.

Comment: Request.Headers["Accept-Language"] is precisely the data I need, and as it is public and provided by the client, I hoped to read it client-side, and spare a round trip to the server. Your second suggestion is actually better as I generate the hosting page from the server anyway. I'll accept your answer if there is no other direct .net call to be found.